# Composer Installation "PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2'"

Tags: php, dll, xampp, composer-php

I am trying to install composer on my system but I am receiving an error "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2'". I downloaded and placed the required `gd_2.dll` file in the folder. Checked `php.ini` for `extension_dir` and it has the absolute path `E:\xampp\php\ext`. Everything seems fine but I am still receiving this error. Please have a look at the screenshot below. In the image you can also see that I have the required `.dll` file highlighted which means I have the file that the installer reported as missing.

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Make sure you have both the correct bit-ness (32/64) as well as thread safety. I have seen misleading PHP messages because of this before on Windows

Comment: Please share more details. It looks suspicious to me that all dll files have the same timestamp, but that single one is eighteen months older

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you have just installed PHP 8. Open your `php.ini` and locate the line near the bottom of the file:

```
[PHP_GD2]
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Change the extension name from php_gd2.dll to php_gd.dll (this should match the one existing in your `ext` directory) and save the php.ini. Run the Composer installation again.

(PHP 8 somehow renamed php_gd2 to php_gd.)

Answer (score -1):

In my php.ini i changed extension=gd2 to extension=gd and it worked

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers. Rather upvote that answer that helped you resolve your problem

Comment: i just wrote it because i didn't have extension=php_gd2.dll in my php.ini but  extension=gd2 and it took me some time to figure out, i did upvote the previous answer, i just want to help i don't care about ratings